# How to connect to Arduino via COM by vendorID, productID or Serial Number

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I can connect to Arduino via simple Windows provided COM interface (`CreateFileW(portName..)`) but you have to know on which COM port Arduino is connected.

How should i find Arduino COM port based on its Serial Number or VendorID and ProductID ? Where to start ? I am new in developing such things, first application of c++ too, so any examples or links are gold.

Comment: I have put an answer, If you be more specific it could better! anyway get started you will find a way! cheers!

Comment: I couldnt possibly put it in any more specific form, since it is what i need. I mean your answer is correct, i will see if i will find any better way or do it your way. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to the computer via COM interface, but as you have a limited number of COM ports you can iterate through comports via `Serial::Serial(char *portName)` and get the specific port. You can use software implementation to get an ID from the arduino and validate it at the Desktop application.